# Android Studio emulator not running for hours

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio

Android studio emulator doesn't run even if the run button was pressed for hours

```
Waiting for device.
"C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools\emulator.exe" -avd MyAvd0 -netspeed full -netdelay none
```

appeared for hours.

It has not running since my second startup for the Android Studio. It faced the fatal error saying that the cache is blocked. After changing the permission of the user for adding full control access, it starts.I did add an sd card of 1024MB for the emulator before.The emulator still not starting up. I have even tried to uninstall and reinstall it

found this now in adb

```
DeviceMonitor: Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host


Starting emulator for AVD 'MyAvd0'
emulator: ERROR: Unable to load VM from snapshot. The snapshot has been saved for a different hardware configuration.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd highly encourage you to try [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/). You'll probably set it up faster than  solving your `avd` issues, and in general terms, it works pretty much better.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot @ssantos. This is an amazing tool working also on my Ubuntu

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like the Snapshot option is enabled for your VM, but you have changed it's config after the snapshot was saved. To fix this try the following:

- Open the **Android Virtual Device Manager**
- Select your AVD, then click the `Edit` button
- In the dialog that shows, **uncheck** the `Snapshot` option (it is under `Emulation Options`).
- Now try to start the emulator again.

Alternately, just open the **Android Virtual Device Manager**, delete the AVD, and create a new AVD.

**Note:**
As [ssantos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1026645/ssantos) mentions, [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) is a fantastic emulator and I personally use it for my day-to-day testing. It is definitely worth checking out if you have the time :)

Comment: I had same problem, and Snapshot option was unchecked. I tried Genymotion and it worked fine.

Comment: Nice catch! Also I don't like it when the solution to a problem is installing new software... (Genymotion is still worth a try of course)

Answer (score 5):

Check while creating the avd in `Android Virtual Device Manager` if there were any warnings, for me there was it said (paraphrasing) "for windows RAM size greater the 768 MB might cause problems in emulator". After making the RAM size 768 MB it worked and started immediately
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar issue but there were no errors in my case, only the emulator keeped on starting but not displaying the home screen.

> So I just Opened the AVD Manager then
>
> Under Actions Tab

- Click the Third Icon (pointing downwards), It will open the some options
- Select Wipe Data

And you are Done :)